# $.mobile.back() let's Windows 10 cordova app crash

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-10

After digging 8 hours around, I found a reproduce for a very strange bug.

A windows-10 App is build by cordova. Once $.mobile.back() is invoked, the application will crash when minimized.

```
Windows Logs (Application):
Event ID: 2484
Task Category: (2400)
Source: Apps
General: Package ... was terminated because it took too long to suspend.
```

Comment: I assume that in a browser on win 10 the JQM app is fine? as a test embed crosswalk and give it a try (cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview) -- crosswalk is a replacement for webviews etc -- https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/cordova/cordova_4.html -- backup your cordova project 1st before you add crosswalk

Comment: @Tasos No support for Windows 10 desktop: https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html

Comment: cool didn't see that,  "Work is also underway to support Windows 10 desktop" so maybe in the next few months.